# Single word describing doing the right thing for the right reason

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I’m looking for a single word or short word group that describes doing the right thing for the right reason, or a person who does the right thing for the right reason

Comment: The body question at the duplicate is 'I'm looking for a word to describe someone who is very driven by morality, constantly trying to do what they believe is morally right.' 'Righteous', 'scrupluous', 'upstanding', 'high-minded', 'principled' ... are suggested (though no single word for the 'practice', righteous conduct, itself). Perhaps 'propriety'.

Answer (score 0):

A word that describes doing the right thing for the right reason is, from [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/integrity)

> **integrity**
>   NOUN
>
> **1** The quality of being honest and having strong moral principles.
>   *a gentleman of complete integrity*

A word that describes a person who has integrity, also in [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/principled), is

> **principled**
>   ADJECTIVE
>
> **1** (of a person or their behaviour) acting in accordance with morality and showing recognition of right and wrong.
>   *a principled politician*